# arm (bare metal): call binary file as function

Tags: c, arm, bare-metal

I have AT91Bootloader for AT91sam9 ARM controller. I need add some extra hardware initialization, but I have only compiled .bin file. 
I loaded bin file to memory and tried to call it:

```
((void (*)())0x00005000)();
```

But, haven't any results. Please use assembler as less as possible. I was introduced to assembler before, but cannot understand ARM assembler due to it's complicity. How can I make call from middle of bootloader, execute bin file (it will be in some memory sector, 0x00005000 for example) and then return to bootloader and continue executing it's own code?

Comment: Too little information given. Btw, if the function that you are calling wasn't compiled and linked for execution at address 0x5000, the above will likely not work (I don't think that that binary contains only position-independent code).

Answer (score 2):

If ARM asm is "too complex", you will find it very difficult to debug any problems you're having. Basic* ARM assembly is one of the *least* complex assembly languages I've come across.

Your code *ought to* work (though I would not use a hard-coded address there) provided the ".bin" is of the correct format. Common issues:

- The entry point should be ARM code; some compilers default to Thumb. It's possible (if a little tricky) to make Thumb code work.
- The entry point needs to be at the start of the file. Without disassembling, it's hard to tell if you've done this correctly.
- The linker will insert "thunks" (a.k.a. "stubs") where necessary. A quirk in some linkers means that the thunk can be placed *before* the entry point. You can work around this by using `--stub-group-size=-1` (docs [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/ARM.html)).

* Ignoring things like Thumb/VFP/NEON which you don't need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

ARM assembly is one of the simpler ones, very straight forward. If you want to continue to do bare metal you are going to need to learn at least some assembly.  For example understanding Alexey's comment.

The instruction you are looking for is BX, it branches to an address, the assembly you need to branch to the code your bootloader downloaded is:

```
.globl tramp
tramp:
   bx r0
```

The C prototype is

```
void tramp ( unsigned int address );
```

As mentioned in the comments the program needs to be compiled for the address you are running it from and/or it needs to be position independent, otherwise it wont work.  Also you need to build the application with the proper entry point, if it is raw binary and you branch to the address where the binary was loaded the binary needs to be able to be started that way by having the first word in the binary be the entry point for execution.

Also understand that an elf format file contains the data you want to load, but as a whole is not the data you want to load.  It is a "binary file" yes but to run the program contained in it you need to parse and extract the loadable portions and load them in the right places.

If you dont know what those terms mean, use google, and/or search SO, the answers are there.